# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I get this error message : "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large"
when I try to run my shiny app.
I've seen in other questions that the problem comes from dimension. (par = ...)
But I can't find solution when it appears in a shiny app.

Here is my server part :

```
work_dir_3 <- "C:\\Users\\François\\Desktop\\SHINY"
setwd(work_dir_3)
getwd()

source("procedure_finale_shiny.R", local = TRUE)

#res1 = as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,c(30,50,60,70,80),c(1,2,3,4))[[1]]) 
#res2 = as.data.frame(procedure_finale_shiny(0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.2,c(30,50,60,70,80),c(1,2,3,4))[[2]])

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  source("procedure_finale_shiny.R", local = TRUE)

  results <- eventReactive(input$calculate, {
    procedure_finale_shiny(
      input$SliderAlpha1, input$SliderAlpha2, input$SliderAlpha3, input$SliderAlpha4, input$SliderAlpha5,
      c(input$SliderRatio1, input$SliderRatio2,input$SliderRatio3, input$SliderRatio4, input$SliderRatio5),
      as.numeric(input$ModeleFinder))
  })

  output$tab_res <- renderDataTable({ results()[[1]] })
  output$best_mod <- renderDataTable({ results()[[2]] })


  output$downloadData1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(file.type = input$Export1) {
      if (file.type == "csv"){
        str <- "my_data.csv"
      }else if (file.type == "texte"){
        str <- "my_data.txt"
      }
      #else if()...etc
      return(str)
    },

    content = function(con){

      my_data <- results()[[1]]

      # input$Export1 is again used in this if-else block to use the 
      # correct function to write the data
      if (input$Export1 == "csv"){
        write.csv(my_data, con, row.names=FALSE)
      }else if (input$Export1 == "texte"){
        write.table(my_data, con)
      }
      #else if...etc

    }

  )

  Base_shiny <- read.csv("base_de_donnees\\Main_Learning_Base_corr.csv" , header = T)

  output$base_donnees <- renderPrint({
    if(input$Display1 == "head"){

      print(head(Base_shiny))
    } 

    if(input$Display1 == "str"){

      print(str(Base_shiny))
    } 

    if(input$Display1 == "summary"){

      print(summary(Base_shiny))
    } 

  })

  Base_shiny_2 <- Base_shiny[,-c(1:4)]

  Base_shiny_3 <- pairs(data.matrix(Base_shiny_2))

  output$graph_sortie <- renderPlot({

    if(input$Display2 == "Modele 1"){

      plot(Base_shiny_3[1,], type='o', xlab="Indice n", ylab = "Valeurs de la série temporelle")
    } 


  })


}
```

I try to plot this element : **Base_shiny_3**

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The way to fix it in shiny is the same as in R: make sure you have sufficient `par(mar=...)` values. In `shiny` you have the added complexity that it is *possible* for the webpage to be too small to hold a reasonably-sized image. You will need to find a way in shiny to enforce a minimum image size (perhaps with scrolling). (Both `plotOutput` and `renderPlot` accept `width, height` arguments, so you can control it that way.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice ! I changed this line : plotOutput("graph_sortie", width = 20, height = 30) in UI part but I can't fixed it. And I can't find the right dimensions ... Maybe you have an example ?

Comment: From [`?plotOutput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/plotOutput.html), *or a number, which will be coerced to a string and have "px"*. So you're saying you want an image 20 [pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) wide ... err, not gonna work.

Comment: I tried with "auto" and with px... in vain.

Comment: You tried `width="20px"`? What about (say) `width = "1000px"`? "auto" will certainly continue to fail, since I'm inferring that your web layout will not allow a reasonable image.

Comment: Yes I did... It doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you plot it in base R without shiny?

Comment: I didn't work in base R. I added some code to my shiny app.